# How to require a type to be not empty

Tags: typescript, types

Suppose I have a type where all properties are optional:

```
type T = {
  x?: number;
  y?: string;
  z?: number;
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to construct a type that will allow all values of type T but requires at least one property? E.g.:

```
let a: NotEmpty<T> = { z: 1 }; // ok
a = {}; // error
```

Of course one way to do this would be a union of all combinations with at least one required property, but this becomes kind of awkward when the number of properties is large.  Is there a more general way?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wk8MDw) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sure, please explain.

Comment: I m also wondering if this approach can be extended when type T is more complex, e.g. type T = ({ x?: number } | { y?: number }) & ({ a?: number} | {b?: number}) ?

Comment: Are you changing the scope of the question while I'm writing an answer?

Comment: No, just an additional question.  I ll accept your answer for the original.

Comment: And what is the expected output for that input?  Is it just "can't be empty" like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wyxbxm) shows?  Or is it something more complicated?

Comment: Sorry, i my example was not complete, it should be: type T = ({ x?: number, y?: never } | { y?: number, x?: never }) & ({ a?: number, b?: never} | {b?: number, a?: never}).  Basically it is a type that allow x or y but not both and a or b but not both.  So, { x: 1, a: 1 } is ok but { x: 1, y: 1, a: 1 } is not.  Now i wanted to make it so that {} is not allowed as well, so at least one property must be present.

Comment: In general, if there is some complex object type, which is not necessarily defined with one interface, i wonder if is it possible to make it non-empty?

Comment: Like [this then](https://tsplay.dev/W4687N)?  I'm not really willing to hash this out further here in the comments section; if you have a more complex example and you want to talk about it in more detail, then you might want to open a new post for it, taking care to present a [mre] that goes over the use cases you're concerned about.

Comment: I guess even for complex object, doing & with union of all single-property objects for all properties of T will still work (if done explicitly), which is not too bad since it is linear in the number of properties like you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I think i understand now that the original answer works for this example too, as in your latest link, since it will also & a union of single-property types.  It seems that the type Expand is to present the type as a top-level union, so it doesn't really change the set of allowed values? The only part i still don't understand is conditional with "T extends unknown" in the beginning.  It's probably too much to create a new post just for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) you're talking about of "all combinations with at least one required property" isn't too bad to write, especially since you can write the `NotEmpty<T>` utility type to compute it automatically.  And that type only has one union member per property key, so it scales well with number of properties (it's not a factorial or combinatorial explosion or anything).

Here's one way to write it:

```
type NotEmpty<T> = T &
  { [K in keyof T]-?: { [P in K]-?: T[K] } }[keyof T];
```

So a `NotEmpty<T>` is `T` [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with something, so we know that, at minimum, `NotEmpty<T>` is a subtype of `T`.  The thing we intersect it with,

```
{ [K in keyof T]-?: { [P in K]-?: T[K] } }[keyof T]
```

is a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)), a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) into which we immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with all of its keys to get a union.   In the above, we get the union of `{[P in K]-?: T[K]}` for every `K` in `keyof T`.

And that type `{[P in K]-?: T[K]}` is equivalent to `Required<Pick<T, K>>` (see [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) and [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) utility types): an object which definitely has a defined `K` property from `T`.

So the whole thing is then: `NotEmpty<T>` is a `T` which is also known to have *some* defined property from the properties in `T`.

---

Let's test it out on your example:

```
type NotEmptyT = NotEmpty<T>
/* type NotEmptyT = T & ({ x: number; } | { y: string; } | { z: number; }) */
```

Looks good, let's make sure it behaves as desired:

```
let a: NotEmpty<T>;
a = { z: 1 }; // ok
a = {}; // error
```

Also looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeAoKUAeB+AXFAdgK4C2ARhAE4DcaUIuUAzsBQJb4DmN6AXg0WUrcoAehEA6SSgC+KFKEhQAcgHtgAUWJhQAHhgA+BLCgAyWkigBtANJR2UANYQQKgGawAugFoGFywAU7fChrbwYYGw8oaWjLJxd3GA8aeXBoVQ0tUDhEDM1tED19FBEAKigFdLV87KM4EygACgsMPAFyamioAB9kOjxmNk4qLt6LHjaSDpHpAEooUpE5ABsIYCgAQzw8rMKDGg2jcbwARmiRsSgVBxRDxCRpC5EoSgoVChQgA)

Comment: Thanks, I think i understand now, [keyof T] at the end will create a union of all value types of what is in {} previously, which would be a union of { [P in K]-?: T[K] } for every key in T.